# on the sheafification of a presheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

There's something bugging me on the theory of sheafification.

I proved that, given $P$ a presheaf on a topological space $X$ , there exists a sheaf $P^*$ and a presheaf homomorphism $f:P\to P^*$ such that for every sheaf $F$ and homomorphism $\varphi:P\to F$ there's a unique $\tilde{\varphi}:P^*\to F$ such that $\tilde{\varphi}\circ f=\varphi$.

But the theorem states also that the following are equivalent:

- $\tilde\varphi$ isomorphism
- $\forall x\in X$ the stalks are isomorphic $\varphi_x:P_x\cong F_x$
- $\varphi$ is locally injective and surjective

I proved also that $P^*_x\cong P_x$ so it's easy to see that the first two are equivalent.
But I have no idea why the last one should be equivalent to the other.. I don't know whether it's wrong or I have the wrong definition for "locally inje/surjective" or simply I'm missing totally the point..

P.s. On a total different side.. how do I draw diagrams here? In Latex I use tikz, but I don't know if it works even here.

Comment: Can you say what locally injective/surjective is ? $P(U)\rightarrow F(U)$ is in/sur ?

Comment: That's an issue for itself. I suppose that it means "$\forall x\in X$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\varphi:P(U)\to F(U)$ is in/sur", but I don't know if it's right

Comment: I would just try to show that $P(U)\rightarrow F(U)$ is an isomorphism for all $U$, this gives the theorem. Since it is a map of presheaves, this may just be what the assumption means.

Comment: No, that's not possible, since there are examples in which  $\varphi$ is not an isomorphism. Moreover, if $P$ is not a sheaf, and you take $F=P^*$, it's  impossible that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism

Comment: Oh OK, so locally in/sur must imply isomorphism on the stalks.

Comment: It should be clear that locally injective/surjective as you have defined it implies that $\phi$ gives an ismorphism on the stalks.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not even clear to me.. I would agree to it if the restrictions were surjective, but that's not the case..

Comment: Oh, sorry! You should change your definition to $\forall x \in X$ and $\forall $ open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ there exists open $V$ such that $x \in V \in U$ and $P(V) \to F(V)$ is an isomorphism.  Otherwise, it's not true. You can make a simple counterexample with a 2 pt topological space.

Comment: ok, with that It's easy to prove one way. And the other? Is it true that an isomorphism on the stalkes induces a locally in/sur omomorphism?

Comment: Yes, more precisely:  if $f: P \to F$ a map of sheaves gives an isomorphism on stalks, then it is an isomorphism on every open subset.  Hint:  prove that it's injective first-- you'll need this to get surjective.

Comment: I know that, but $P$ is only a presheaf, so $f:P\to F$ isn't a map of sheaves!

Comment: meant $P^*$ instead of $P$

Comment: @Phil Ok, I know that a map of sheaves giving an isomorphism on the stalks is an isomorphism.. But how does this imply that the map of presheaves is locally in/sur?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18706/discussion-between-phil-and-exodd).